# Making a Categorized Gallery in Wordpress - Approach suggestions

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I'm making a site for a friend (artist). He wishes to have a gallery. The requirements are as follows:

- Allow users to comment:

  - Registered user - Comment normally.
  - Unregistered user - reCaptcha comment + link to registration (which should also have reCaptcha, but that's another story).
- Galleries should have categories, and each category should have a page of its own, visible in the menu (or a specially constructed `categorylist-page.php`).
- Ability to moderate comments and spam.

I've though of 2 possible things:

1. Each image should be a static page, which will be a child of its categorizing page.

   - Pros: Uses native wordpress abilities. Easy moderation through admin panel.
   - Cons: Possibly add complexity for the administrator (who is not a programmer)
2. Try to find a plugin to do the job, but so far I haven't found one which answers the requirements above.

I was hoping to get a nudge in the right direction, I'm no wordpress expert.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first approach is best, assuming that you want visitors to comment on individual artworks, and not just general gallery comments.

You might be able to get away with just using Posts and setting the Featured Image, but if you find yourself wanting more flexibility, custom fields, and possibly custom post types and taxonomies, definitely check out [MagicFields](http://magicfields.org/)

As for the commenting/spam prevention requirements, I wouldn't require users to create an account, unless they are already raving fans of your friend's artwork. Instead, I'd:

1. Pay for an Akismet key, or
2. Use Disqus, IntenseDebate, or [Facebook Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/)

Comment: Won't it be complex for the admin to upload images? What would be the process assuming he wants to add a new artwork into the "Landscape" category, what would he need to do? Great answer nevertheless, +1

Comment: Assuming you create a custom post type called "Artwork" using MagicFields, it would look like this. 1) Click Artwork > Add New Artwork. 2) Enter a title & description. 3) Upload image(s) to MagicFields Custom Fields area. Fill in any other custom fields, like medium, dimensions, etc. 4) Check the categories/subcategories the art belongs to. 5) Save.